# Android Studio, Activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I accidentally clicked something somewhere I think and now my project won't build/run. When I click Run, it Just get message stating "Error running MainActivity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter"

what can I do to fix this error?

When I click on that error I get a huge log stating:

```
  10/19 11:54:27: Launching app
 Split APKs installed
 $ adb shell am start -n       "com.example.robjohns.something/com.example.robjohns.something.Introduction" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2181 on device Nexus_5X_API_24 [emulator-5554]
Application terminated.
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

EDIT: I updated my AndroidManifest.xml and now when I build/run app, it starts from my MainActivity file instead of how it's supposed to start from my Introduction file. HOW DO I GET IT TO START FROM INTRODUCTION FILE?

I know there are others who posted this question but those answerers said to add   "android:exported="true"   which I did but nothing changed.

Comment: Sometimes Android Studio goofs up. You can try by clicking on on File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..

Comment: What is the error when you hover your mouse over the text?

Comment: Hi, i just edited my above error. Now I uploaded a new AndroidManifest.xml. now the project builds with no error but it builds the MainActivity file. But it's supposed to start from the Introduction file. What do I change in AndroidManifest to make it start from Introduction instead?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the red-lined file is not in the original folder, try looking for the actifity file, good luck

Comment: It has nothing to do with BroadcastTabBar, GroupsTabBar and WorldTabBar. I had those in red before and everything worked fine. Then I clicked something somewhere and I got the above message. So it's something else.

Comment: if so take a look at the android monitor, there will be an error lies where

Comment: No, when I click RUN, Android monitor is blank. However, When I do click Run it says  "RUN 'MainActivity' (^R)"  But my first activity is actually Introduction activity. Does this has something to do with it? Why does it say "run main activity" instead of "run introduction activity"? Can that be something that's wrong there?

Comment: when you run mainactivity is okay, and when you run Introduction error, right? if it is so the problem exists in that file or files associated with it. suggestions I see on the monitor android there must be an error that appears there, or console log something that can be logged from the file

Comment: if you click on the arrow near the "play" icon, in the menu you can select "Edit run configurations..." . Edit the current configuration and manually specify the activity to run, to see if it helps.

Comment: Actually, I just updated my AndroidManifest.xml (above). However, with this updated AndroidManifest.xml now the project build and runs. However, the first activity it shows me is MainActivity's xml file. But it's supposed to show me Introduction's xml file. What can I change in AndroidManifest.xml to make it show me Introduction.xml first as it's supposed to be?

Comment: in the file androidmanifest sure the first run is your introduction file.

Comment: Actually I figured out, it has nothing to do with AndroidManifest. All I had to do was click Run, Edit configurations and for some reason MainActivity  somehow became my default activity. So I had to change that to Introduction. Don't know how that just changed on its own initially though.

Comment: I do not know what you actually do so that it changes, only that input can I give